# make error > depends on non-existent package gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

i have gazebo , i installed gazebo with synaptic and i can open it with "$gazebo" in terminal.
when i make hector_gazebo_plugins package, it gave me this error :( any body help?

```
mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~/fuerte_workspace/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins$ make
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package hector_gazebo_plugins
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests hector_gazebo_plugins
[rospack] Error: package/stack hector_gazebo_plugins depends on non-existent package gazebo


CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
  


  Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
  'hector_gazebo_plugins'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
  Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Error 1
mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~/fuerte_workspace/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2060/make-error-%3E-depends-on-non-existent-package-gazebo/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/242/mohsen-hk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is probably due to `hector_gazebo_plugins` depending on a version of Gazebo that was packaged with ROS Fuerte.

Take a look in the examples directory within the Gazebo sources for CMakeLists.txt that build against the system install of Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0